# logrotate doesn't work for munin after last update on OpenSUSE 11.4

Tags: permissions, opensuse, logrotate, munin

I'm using munin 1.4.5 on OpenSUSE 11.4. Lately logrotate was updated to fix some permission problems and after that complained with

```
Mar  3 12:15:05 lucien logrotate: error: "/var/log/munin" has insecure permissions. It must be owned and be writable by root only to avoid security problems. Set the "su" directive in the config file to tell logrotate which user/group should be used for rotation.
Mar  3 12:15:05 lucien logrotate: error: error reading /var/log/munin/munin-html.log: Bad file descriptor
Mar  3 12:15:05 lucien logrotate: error: error reading /var/log/munin/munin-limits.log: Bad file descriptor
Mar  3 12:15:05 lucien logrotate: error: error reading /var/log/munin/munin-update.log: Bad file descriptor
Mar  3 12:15:05 lucien logrotate: error: error reading /var/log/munin/munin-graph.log: Bad file descriptor
Mar  3 12:15:05 lucien logrotate: error: error reading /var/log/munin/munin-node.log: Bad file descriptor
```

So I addded `su` directives to `/etc/logrotate.d/munin` and `/etc/logrotate.d/munin-node`:

```
/var/log/munin/munin-html.log
/var/log/munin/munin-nagios.log
/var/log/munin/munin-limits.log
/var/log/munin/munin-update.log {
    su munin munin
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 7
    compress
    copytruncate
    notifempty
    create 640 munin munin
}
/var/log/munin/munin-graph.log {
    su munin www
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 7
    compress
    copytruncate
    notifempty
    create 660 munin www
}
/var/log/munin/munin-cgi-graph.log {
    su wwwrun munin
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 7
    compress
    copytruncate
    notifempty
    create 640 wwwrun www
}

/var/log/munin/munin-node.log {
    su munin munin
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 7
    compress
    copytruncate
    notifempty
    create 640 munin munin
}
```

Now logrotate doesn't rotate anymore.

```
Mar  5 12:15:05 lucien logrotate: error: error reading /var/log/munin/munin-html.log: Bad file descriptor
Mar  5 12:15:05 lucien logrotate: error: error reading /var/log/munin/munin-limits.log: Bad file descriptor
Mar  5 12:15:05 lucien logrotate: error: error reading /var/log/munin/munin-update.log: Bad file descriptor
Mar  5 12:15:05 lucien logrotate: error: error reading /var/log/munin/munin-graph.log: Bad file descriptor
Mar  5 12:15:05 lucien logrotate: error: error setting owner of /var/log/munin/munin-cgi-graph.log-20120305: Operation not permitted
Mar  5 12:15:05 lucien logrotate: error: error opening /var/log/munin/munin-node.log: Permission denied
```

An `ls -la` of `/var/log/munin/` is [here](http://pastebin.com/zfsyz4Pr).

How do I get logrotate to work again with munin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a [bug](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=751358) introduced in `logrotate-3.7.9-6.9.1` and fixed in `logrotate-3.7.9-6.12.1`.

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a mess in your permissions in */var/log/munin* and in your config file. You have different user/group pair for your files and diffrent group/pair in your configuration.

You have 2 choices in order to solve your problem

1. Use default root:root permissions
2. Specify in *ALL* your munin rules the same user/group pair

First, you can reset permissions recursively with chown :

```
chown -R USER:GROUP /var/log/munin
```

After, if you choose the second solution, you'll have to replace all `su ...` lines with this one :

```
su USER GROUP
```

If you choose the first solution, you'll have to remove entirely all `su ...` lines.

Comment: I have different permissions because I use munin-cgi and so some log files must be writeable by the webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Run logrotate manually as root with '-d' (as debug) and you will see nice talkative outout.

Comment: It is: 'su' option has been added by the latest maintenance update to deal with the security issues with service owned directories: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?GoAheadAndLogIn=1&id=677335

Comment: OK then, my logrotate is outdated :)